# output error in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have problem with working with calculator class in `xcode`. 
I have the code attached for reference. 
Since I am a novice in the learning phase any help shall be really appreciated.
The error is that of incomplete implementation.

```
// Working with Calculator class
// What required shall be a class where we can perform 4 basic operations of +,-,/,* using accumulator which we can set to some value and perform operations on it and then also return its value, also clear it for some other operation.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Calculator:NSObject
{
    double accumulator;// type of variables employed

}
-(void) setAccumulator:(double)value; // Declaring the methods employed
-(void) clearAccumulator;
-(double) Accumulator;
// Method declaration for calculation - Arithematic Methods
-(void)subtract : (double) value;
-(void) add : (double) value;
-(void) multiply : (double) value;
-(void) divide : (double) value;
@end

@implementation Calculator // defining the methods declared in interface section

-(void) setAccuumulator:(double)value
{
    accumulator=value;
}
-(void) clearAccumulator
{
    accumulator = 0;
}
-(double) Accumulator
{
    return accumulator;
}
-(void) subtract : (double)value
{
    accumulator -= value;
}
-(void) add : (double) value
{
    accumulator += value;
}
-(void) multiply : (double) value
{
    accumulator *= value;
}
-(void) divide : (double) value
{
    accumulator /= value;
}
@end
// Program section as usual begins with the main
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool =[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Calculator * deskCal = [[Calculator alloc] init];

    [deskCal setAccumulator: 100.0];
    [deskCal add :200.0];
    [deskCal divide : 15.0];
    [deskCal subtract : 10.0];
    [deskCal multiply : 5.0];

    NSLog(@" The result is %g", [deskCal Accumulator]);
    [deskCal release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 'incomplete implementation' error should tell you which methods you haven't implemented - can you add the error output to your question?

Comment: @deanWombourne he is probably getting `NSInvalid  exception` because he has misspelled his function

Comment: I was more interested in _which_ function - I couldn't see it in the question. Looks like you spotted it though :) I also wanted him to realise that the compiler was telling him where it was wrong and he just hadn't seen it.

Comment: Yes you are right. the error was simply in the way i typed accumulator. thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @SpaceDust Thanks a lot. I was offline for sometime due to viral. But now I am back.

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelled the `-(void) setAccumulator:(double)value` function of your class

simply change your misspelled

```
-(void) setAccuumulator:(double)value
{
    accumulator=value;
}
```

to

```
-(void) setAccumulator:(double)value
{
    accumulator=value;
}
```

this gives you

```
The result is 50
```

Answer (score -2):

In Xcode, open the organizer window and enter 'Calculator'.  In the list that results, under Sample Code, will be a project labeled 'Unit Tests'.  Download and build this project, then take a look at the implementation.

While this project is mostly designed for showing how to use the testing framework, it also include a calculator sample app, which should answer many of your questions.  Other sample code and tutorials can also be found this way.

Good luck!